# Unix - How to print last lines of a file and each time ignore the first same character?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, console

I am using following command to print the content of a file at the bottom

```
tail --lines=+$(($LINENO + 1)) ~/.zshrc
```

After that command follows a table showing information about my file.
This information has to be written with `#` in front of each line so it's a comment.

Therefore the print shows the `#`, too.

How do I ignore the first character in each line when printing the content after my `tail` command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pipe to a `sed`:

```
tail --lines=+$(($LINENO + 1)) ~/.zshrc | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*#//'
```

Comment: If you're going to use `sed`, might as well drop the tail. `sed -n -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*#//' -e "$((LINENO+1)),\$p"`